# param is missing or the value is empty: user_club - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I want to call create action of controller **user_clubs** and I did this way:

**View Clubs**

```
<button> 
   <%= link_to "Join Club", user_clubs_path(:user_id => current_user.id, :club_id => @club.id, :join_date => Date.current), :method => :post %>
</button>
```

**Controller user_clubs**

```
def create
    @user_club = UserClub.new(user_club_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user_club.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user_club, notice: 'User club was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user_club }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user_club.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

def user_club_params
  params.require(:user_club).permit(:user_id, :club_id, :join_date) --->**Error here**
end
```

**Error information**

**app/controllers/user_clubs_controller.rb:75:in `user_club_params'
app/controllers/user_clubs_controller.rb:28:in`create'
Request**

```
    Parameters:

    {"_method"=>"post",
     "authenticity_token"=>"5Grhb+LIGt9B8XbnEcvg7BZQlDE935KO/aeikZoqxYs=",
     "club_id"=>"1",
     "join_date"=>"2014-11-17",
     "user_id"=>"2"

}
```

Clubs and UserClubs are different. Club is a model that represents a team of people and user_clubs is the model that represents the many-to-many relationship between Users and Clubs.

**First, can someone explain me how the call to user_clubs_path followed by the arguments know that has to go to the action create of user_clubs controller?**

In second, the objective problem, why is this an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question**

Because of your routes definition, type into a terminal:

```
rake routes
```

And you'll see all generated routes and its associated helpers. First column (rake output) references the named helper: user_clubs => user_clubs_path):

**Second question**

You should add the parameters into `user_club` key, because you're requiring (by strong_parameters) this "scope" `params.require(:user_club)`:

```
user_clubs_path(:user_club => {:user_id => current_user.id, :club_id => @club.id, :join_date => Date.current})
```

You'll receive in the controller:

```
{
  "_method" => "post",
  "authenticity_token" => "...",
  "user_club" => {
    "club_id" => "1",
    "join_date"=> "2014-11-17",
    "user_id"=> "2"
  }
}
```

Comment: so, that is the way to create a resource without have to fill de _form, right?

Comment: yes, kind of Rails magic :), when you add `:method => :post` Rails will convert that link to a form (via internal js): http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Comment: Thank you. I'm learning the basics and I came from programming languages like java and C and at the start is not simple to abstract of that sintax. Thank you again :-)

Comment: You're welcome @Silva_PT_SCP, I also came from Java and C, in a short time you'll love Ruby. If you need Ruby resources/tools/plugins, we are building a collection of MVP Ruby, take a look https://github.com/markets/awesome-ruby

Comment: Thank you again @markets! I will take a look soon as I can! Greetings from Portugal!

Answer (score 1):

The parameters need to be nested under the `user_club` key. Try this instead:

```
user_clubs_path(:user_club => {:user_id => current_user.id, :club_id => @club.id, :join_date => Date.current})
```